# How to transmit uv and texture when using Tissue

Tags: modeling, uv, add-on

[image]

When I create a mesh using a tissue, the material and texture are transferred from the source mesh, but the UV is not transmitted.

I can manually edit the UV because the result in the above image is simple.

However, if the density of the pattern becomes more complicated, UV editing becomes too difficult.

Let me know if you have a way to transmit UVs in the Tissue or easily edit complex UV patterns.

--(new image)

[image: new image]

Comment: i think before 1st uvwrap on that small part and then make use of the tissue addon

Comment: Please explain in more detail.

Answer (score -1):

With the small part of the mesh selected apply scale and rotation and unwrap the image.

Take a mesh that tissue is going to apply (i have taken a cube and subdivide few times)

Select the small mesh and hold shift and click Cube and click on tessellate in tool shelf

Now we got the new shape of the mesh from the Addon with no material and no uv applied to it. Go to edit mode and select all faces and Press Ctrl+N (flip Normal)

In the Edit mode Press L key on one face which select the small part of the mesh.

With the small face selected Press Shift+G -> Area

And now the complete mesh is selected

Press U to unwrap

And apply material on to it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I used Susan Objects to convey my questions more specifically. (Check the attached new photo in the question.) For objects with curved surfaces, your method is not right. What is the best way to use tissue and tile textures together?